# Query results and pagination showing first page only

Tags: search, mysqli

I am trying to build a scraper for educational purposes only, I am using Phasher class to generate Hexadecimal hashes and store in the database then search the stored images for similar images, I wrote something a few days ago trying to show the results for the search for similar pictures but I can't figure out why it's showings only the results on first page only and other pages doesn't show them whe I press on number 1 page it doesn't show anything but the results are correct and the number of generated are correct I am new in PHP and I am trying to learn it by doing any help will appreciate it thanks in advance.

This is index.php

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
        <img alt="FBpp logo" src="images/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

    <div class="container"><!--container-->

        <h3>Search Facebook Profiles Pictures For Similar Pictures.</h3>
        <p>Please upload a picture, Allowed extensions are (jpg, jpeg, pjpeg, png, x-png) and maximum size is 5 Mb...</p>

    <?php

    //Require config.php file to connect with mysql server and the db.
    require_once('config.php');

    //Check if the database is empty or if there are hashed pictures then show the number of hashed pictures.
    $check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM images ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0){

        $max_id = mysqli_fetch_row($check);

        $id = $max_id[0];

        echo 'We scraped '; echo '<span class="bg-info">'.$id.'</span>'; echo ' pictures...';
    }else{
        echo 'The database is empty you need to run scraper.php';
    }
    ?>

    <br /><br />
    <form action="search.php" method="post" class="form-inline reset-margin" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="image" class="file-input">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
    </div>
    </form>
    <br />

    <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

This is search.php

```
<?php

include('header.php');

//Require config.php file to connect with mysql server and the db.
require_once('config.php');

include_once('classes/phasher.class.php');
$I = PHasher::Instance();

require_once('classes/paginator.class.php');

$limit      = ( isset( $_GET['limit'] ) ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
$page       = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
$links      = ( isset( $_GET['links'] ) ) ? $_GET['links'] : 7;


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $allowedExts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'pjpeg', 'png', 'x-png');
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);

    //Check if the extenstion of the uploaded picture is correct and the max size is 5*1024*1024 Megabits.
    if((($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/x-png"))
        && ($_FILES["image"]["size"] <= 5242880)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){

        //Check if there is an error in the file, If not upload it to tmp folder then check db for similar pictures.
        if($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0){
            echo "Return Code: " .$_FILES["image"]["error"]."<br />";
        } else {

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], dirname(__file__)."/tmp/".$_FILES["image"]["name"]);

            $uploadedImage = dirname(__file__)."/tmp/".$_FILES["image"]["name"];

            if($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 0){

                $hash = $I->FastHashImage($uploadedImage);
                $hex = $I->HashAsString($hash);

                $query = "SELECT `fid`,`hash` FROM `images` WHERE `hash` LIKE '%".$hex."%'";

                $queryResult = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($queryResult);

                echo "<p>" .$numrows. " results found for " .$_FILES['image']['name']. "</p><br />";

                $Paginator  = new Paginator( $con, $query );
                $results    = $Paginator->getData( $limit, $page );

                //Loop through result set.
                /*while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($selectQuery)){

                    if($row['hash'] == $hex){

                        $fid = $row['fid'];
                        echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/$fid/' target='_blank'><img src='http://localhost/fbpp/test_pics/$fid.jpg' alt='' class='img-responsive'></a><br />";
                        // echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/$fid/' target='_blank'><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/$fid/picture?type=large' alt='' class='img-responsive'></a><br />";
                    }
                }*/



                echo '<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-rounded"><tbody>';

                for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ){

                    if($results->data[$i]["hash"] == $hex){

                        echo '<tr>';
                        $fid = $results->data[$i]['fid'];
                        echo "<td><a href='https://www.facebook.com/$fid/' target='_blank'><img src='http://localhost/fbpp/test_pics/$fid.jpg' alt='' class='img-responsive'></a></td>";
                        // echo "<td><a href='https://www.facebook.com/$fid/' target='_blank'><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/$fid/picture?type=large' alt='' class='img-responsive'></a></td>";
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }
                }

                if($numrows <= 10)
                {
                    echo "";
                } else {
                    echo '</tbody></table>';
                    echo $Paginator->createLinks( $links, 'pagination pagination-sm' );
                    echo '</div>';
                }



        }
        //Else after checking the file size.
        else {
                echo "Picture is corrupted the size is 0";
            }

        } //Else after error check.
    }

    // This else after checking the picture extenstion and max size.
    else {
            echo "<p>Please Upload A Picture, Max. size is 5 Mb.</p>";
        }
}

include('footer.php');

?>
```

This is pagination class if you want to look at it:

```
<?php
```

class Paginator {

```
private $_conn;
private $_limit;
private $_page;
private $_query;
private $_total;

public function __construct( $conn, $query ) {

    $this->_conn = $conn;
    $this->_query = $query;

    $rs= $this->_conn->query( $this->_query );
    $this->_total = $rs->num_rows;

}

public function getData( $limit = 10, $page = 1 ) {

    $this->_limit   = $limit;
    $this->_page    = $page;

    if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
        $query      = $this->_query;
    } else {
        $query      = $this->_query . " LIMIT " . ( ( $this->_page - 1 ) * $this->_limit ) . ", $this->_limit";
    }

    $rs             = $this->_conn->query( $query );

    while ( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $results[]  = $row;
    }

    $result         = new stdClass();
    $result->page   = $this->_page;
    $result->limit  = $this->_limit;
    $result->total  = $this->_total;
    $result->data   = $results;

    return $result;
}

public function createLinks( $links, $list_class ) {
    if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
        return '';
    }

    $last       = ceil( $this->_total / $this->_limit );

    $start      = ( ( $this->_page - $links ) > 0 ) ? $this->_page - $links : 1;
    $end        = ( ( $this->_page + $links ) < $last ) ? $this->_page + $links : $last;

    $html       = '<ul class="' . $list_class . '">';

    $class      = ( $this->_page == 1 ) ? "disabled" : "";
    $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page - 1 ) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';

    if ( $start > 1 ) {
        $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=1">1</a></li>';
        $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
    }

    for ( $i = $start ; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {
        $class  = ( $this->_page == $i ) ? "active" : "";
        $html   .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
    }

    if ( $end < $last ) {
        $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
        $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . $last . '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
    }

    $class      = ( $this->_page == $last ) ? "disabled" : "";
    $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page + 1 ) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';

    $html       .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

}

For more information about this you can look at latest commit on my github account:

github.com/jadolyo/FBpp

Thanks in advance I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well with a lot of thinking reading and debugging I had to write the code from scratch again in OOP and I discovered that I need to use sessions because the value of the image path was empty or not completed when I press on any page of the paginator anyway here is the complete code if someone looking for an answer for the same problem...

```
<?php

session_start();

class Search{

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
    * Upload posted image from index.php to tmp dir
    * @return string
    */
    function uploadImage()
    {

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], dirname(__file__).'/tmp/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);

        $uploadedImage = dirname(__file__).'/tmp/'.$_FILES['image']['name'];

        $_SESSION['image'] = $uploadedImage;
    }
        return $_SESSION['image'];
    }

    function imageHashing()
    {
        include_once('classes/phasher.class.php');
        $I = PHasher::Instance();

        $hash = $I->FastHashImage(Search::uploadImage());
        $hex = $I->HashAsString($hash);

        $query = "SELECT `fid`,`hash` FROM `images` WHERE `hash` LIKE '%".$hex."%'";

        //echo $query;
        return $query;
    }

    function imageResults()
    {
        require_once('config.php');

        require_once('classes/paginator.class.php');

        $limit      = ( isset( $_GET['limit'] ) ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
        $page       = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
        $links      = ( isset( $_GET['links'] ) ) ? $_GET['links'] : 7;


        $queryResults = mysqli_query($con, Search::imageHashing());

        $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($queryResults);

        echo "<p>" .$numrows. " results found.</p><br />";

        $Paginator  = new Paginator( $con, Search::imageHashing() );
        $results    = $Paginator->getData( $limit, $page );

        for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ){
                echo '<tr>';
                $fid = $results->data[$i]['fid'];
                echo '<td>';
                echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/$fid/' target='_blank'>https://www.facebook.com/$fid/</a>";
                echo "<a href='https://www.facebook.com/$fid/' target='_blank'><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/$fid/picture?type=large' alt='' class='img-responsive'></a>";
                $name = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fid.'?fields=name&access_token=748352698603001|94fc98094ca42f974879c56f3229c5e4';
                $response = file_get_contents($name);
                $user = json_decode($response,true);
                echo $user['name'];
                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
            if($numrows <= 10){
                echo "";
            } else {
                echo '</tbody></table>';
                echo $Paginator->createLinks( $links, 'pagination pagination-sm' );
                echo '</div>';
            }
    }
}

//Search::uploadImage();
//Search::imageHashing();
Search::imageResults();
?>
```